# Getting element is not attached exception even when element is present on the webpage

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to click on a button but I am getting element is not attached exception even when element is present and I am able to locate element through firebug on Firefox. I am using chrome browser. Is there any way of resolving this issue

Comment: maybe the element wasn't loaded at the time selenium tried to click it?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of ajax or javascript changed the dom. Refer [stale element reference](http://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/stale_element_reference.jsp). We are using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf) and it deals with dynamic elements and such kind of exceptions. Before using QAF we were also facing similar stale element reference exceptions and other issues.